# Valid Lighthouse URL patterns

Tags: google-chrome, seo, performance-testing, lighthouse

I can see that the Lighthouse CLI accepts a `--blocked-url-patterns` argument, but I can't find any definition of what constitutes a valid pattern, only that `*` is supported.

Is `*` literally the only supported pattern-ish character?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is coming in a little (two years) late, but for anyone else who wants to pass block patterns using the CLI you need to pass each pattern as its own param:

```
lighthouse https://example.com --blocked-url-patterns='http://*.evil.com' --blocked-url-patterns='*.jpg'
```

This will create the array required by Lighthouse - which you can see in the report produced if you search for `blockedUrlPatterns`

```json
"blockedUrlPatterns":["http://*.evil.com","*.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this [Google Lighthouse test file](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/test/gather/gather-runner-test.js#L608) `blockedUrlPatterns` is an array of string with various patterns.

```
blockedUrlPatterns: ['http://*.evil.com', '.jpg', '.woff2'],
```

Comment: Looks like a yes.

Comment: Thanks, have you checked if it also supports regular expressions?